# Issue with wordpress + apache vhost

Tags: wordpress, apache

I have installed a wordpress in a virtual host (Apache).  Installation and setup worked like a charm. I can access to wp-login.php without problem, I can do all stuff in the wp-admin/ content but when I try to go to the site there is a redirection that so far I cannot figure out:

My vhost configuration:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
#
# NOTE: NameVirtualHost cannot be used without a port specifier
# (e.g. :80) if mod_ssl is being used, due to the nature of the
# SSL protocol.
#

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for requests without a known
# server name.
#

#Default site
<VirtualHost *:80>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin mail@mail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/wp/html
    ServerName wp.domain.net
    ServerAlias wp.domain.net
    ErrorLog logs/wp.domain.net-error_log
    CustomLog logs/wp.domain.net-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

In WP I have just install a theme no other modification done.

/var/www/vhosts/wp/html contains WP files (index.php, wp-config.php, etc)

This is the redirection I got using chrome:

```
Remote Address:192.168.56.21:80
Request URL:http://wp.domain.net/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:301 Moved Permanently
Request Headers
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Cookie:wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; wordpress_logged_in_24f5535023d725030a9c017d40513418=wp_domain%7C1401501745%7C842283928c4bd862a05205e18d9b6314; wp-settings-time-1=1401328965
DNT:1
Host:wp.domain.net
Pragma:no-cache
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
Response Headers
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:20
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 29 May 2014 02:10:49 GMT
Location:http://wp.domain.nethttp/wp.domain.net/
Server:Apache
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Pingback:http://wp.domain.net/xmlrpc.php
```

As you can see `Location:http://wp.domain.nethttp/wp.domain.net/` in the response has the path to the site twice

What am I missing? I have no touch .htaccess, it is as in the tar file

Thanks in advance for you help...

Adding .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Can you post your .htaccess ?

Comment: Trying remove the ServerAlias or just comment it out to test.

Comment: Yes I already have tried that and still the same, I rename the index.php to index.php_bk and created a new index.php having "echo 5+5;" and I got the right output in the browser so I suppose index.php from WP tar is doing something else, but so far no clue

Comment: Does it work if you add `define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://wp.domain.net/');` and `define('WP_HOME', 'http://wp.domain.net/');` to `wp-config.php`? It seems like your redirects might be broken, you could also try going to `wp-admin` and resaving them.

Comment: Also try switching back to the default twenty-fourteen theme to see if it works with that, might be bad code in the theme.

Comment: neither changing theme nor the defines for WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME.  I have remove the vhost configuration in order to test if is any bug with the installation and not everything is ok working with the ip, is any additional configuration required when working with vhosts in apache? I have a server blocks running in nginx and I do not have any problem